# How to Implement Submenu Using wp_nav_menu

Tags: menus

Though I know that there's may few questions available on this topic, but I need help to implement below dropdown menu using wp_nav_menu.

```
       <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md  navbar-light bg-light">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarMenu">
              <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto">
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link active" href="index.html">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Business</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                  <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="category.html" id="dropdown04" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Travel</a>
                  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown04">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="category.html">Asia</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="category.html">Europe</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="category.html">Dubai</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="category.html">Africa</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="category.html">South America</a>
                  </div>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                  <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="category.html" id="dropdown05" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Categories</a>
                  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown05">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="category.html">Lifestyle</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="category.html">Food</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="category.html">Adventure</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="category.html">Travel</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="category.html">Business</a>
                  </div>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="about.html">About</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="contact.html">Contact</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </nav>
```

Please help me to implement this menu using wp_nav_menu.

Thanks in advance.